# Using credentials.yml with Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I have an app on Rails 5.2 and it was previously hosted on DigitalOcean, but I need to host it on heroku. I've been reading that heroku can't read Credentials.yml of because it's on gitignore and of course I don't want it public.

So my key variables are like this (and example with redis):

```
host: Rails.application.credentials.redis_host,
  password: Rails.application.credentials.redis_password
```

Heroku can't read this. So my question is what is the best approach to change that in to heroku ENV variables? Do I need to edit all my current keys (there about 340) to ENV['SOMEKEY']?

I'll appreciate you help!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create credentials.yml and master key:

```
rails credentials:edit
```

Edit credentails:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

WORKING WITH VIM:

- For inserting
- Press i //Do required editing
- For exiting Press Esc
- :wq //for exiting and saving
- :q! //for exiting without saving

EXAMPLE OF HOW CREDENTIALS.YML can look:

```
development:
   github:
      client: acascascsacascascasc
      secret: vdsvsvg34g34g
production:
   github:
      client: 34g3rvv
      secret: erberb43
```

FIND A CREDENTIAL:

```
rails c
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id)
```

or if an env variable is used

```
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws][:access_key_id]
```

**The credentials.yml file should NOT be in gitignore.**

**The master key that decrypts the credentials SHOULD be in gitignore.**

**To set your master key in production:**

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=123456789
```

or

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key`
```

That's all you need to know about credentials in Ruby on Rails. Good luck :)

#### Update: [I've created a screencast covering the topic :)](https://youtu.be/nDJE8WG0auE)

Comment: This is the most amazing explantion. Thanks, it worked!!

Comment: Great answer. My credentials file came with `secret_key_base`, should it be in your example file ? e.g. should it go before/after the `development:
   github:
      client` etc in the example?

Comment: `secret_key_base` is always there. just leave it on the bottom of the file, not nested under anything

Comment: I am confused about the credentials.  If I add the production credentials via vim, and then save and push to github as a branch, once we merge to master, aren't the credentials gone?  If someone needs to test my branch, don't they have to re-add the credentials?

Also, is this correct then for the gitignore:


/config/master.key
/config/credentials/development.key
/config/credentials/production.key

Comment: you don't keep your github password on github, right? the same way master.key is not kept on github. it is a secret. that is shared in development environment and in production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 6 introduced built-in support for multiple environment credentials

It can be very convenient to keep different secrets for different environments

To create credentials for production environment, we can run the following command

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit --environment production
```

The above command does the following:

- creates `config/credentials/production.key` if missing (don't commit this file, add to `.gitignore` if such record is absent)
- creates `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` if missing (cmmit this file)
- decrypts and opens the production credentials file in vim (you can specify other editor)

And finally we can use these secrets on Heroku

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/credentials/production.key`
```