# Detecting rails configuration failed set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug

Tags: heroku

I have a previous deployed version on heroku and when i checked the logs; the deployment was successful without this:

WARNING:

```
   Detecting rails configuration failed
   set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
```

My current deployment has the following errors in the logs, hence when i deploy, i get "Application Error".

My question is this:

1. How do i clone a working version of my application on heroku?
   When i use the following command,

$ heroku git:clone -a appname
$ cd appname

it clones to my pc, but when i redeploy it, i get "Application Error" on the website and the following in the logs:

WARNING:

```
   Detecting rails configuration failed
   set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
```

Note: The website is running, but redeploying the same clone version, breaks the website, hence it throws "Application Error".

How do i resolve this situation?
I seriously need help around this.

I look forward to your response.
Best regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a solution by now, but in case others came across your question like I did when an app of mine that I had cloned would not run (while the original was still running).

I checkout the logs via `heroku logs` and it appeared the third party service methods to get information from `credentials.yml.enc` were failing. I figured the clone needed the original `master.key`, so I set it with syntax from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011541/using-credentials-yml-with-heroku-on-rails-5-2#62011825):

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key`
```

This restarted the app, and it's running, now onto other issues getting the database schema loaded ;)

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this solution worked. What this does is create an environment variable in Heroku.