# Ruby on Rails 6 - Credentials preventing rake tasks from loading on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm trying to upgrade an app from Rails 6 to Rails 6.1.6.1 and I'm running into the following error using credentials. My production credentials file contains the following:

```yaml
aws:
  bucket_prefix: "some-prefix"
```

But when I try to deploy to Heroku, I'm getting the following:

```rb
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!

 !     NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

 !     
 !     config.dynamic_assets.bucket_prefix = Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_prefix]
 !     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The app starts up just fine with `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` locally.

Would someone please point me as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure thats the file you actually have commited on Heroku? Have you tried running `heroku run rails credentials:edit` to verify it or simple stuff like checking the files checksum?

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that `Rails.application.credentials.aws` is returning `nil`.

What this *usually* means is that Heroku doesn't have your `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`, so it can't access your `credentials.yml.enc` file.

Using the Heroku dashboard or the CLI, you need to set an environment variable called `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to match the key in your `master.key` file.

For a great walkthrough, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011825/1880203).

If you have set this environment variable, check to make sure you haven't added `credentials.yml.enc` to your `.gitignore` list.

If Heroku doesn't have your `credentials.yml.enc` file, then it can't access the credentials inside it, even with the master key.