# Rails 7 - Heroku push : Error Build failed

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-7, omniauth-linkedin

Heroku push : Error Build failed

I am developing a Ruby on Rails 7 web application that uses the omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 gem for LinkedIn authentication. The app works fine locally with the LinkedIn credentials defined in config/credentials.yml.enc. However, when I try to deploy the app to Heroku, I get the following error during asset precompilation:
vbnet

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass config.omniauth :linkedin, Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:client_id], Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:client_secret] 
I have checked that the LinkedIn credentials are correctly set up in both config/credentials.yml.enc and on the Heroku app’s config vars.
Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Installing font-awesome-sass 6.4.0
       Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 81 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Post-install message from devise:
       
       [DEVISE] Please review the [changelog] and [upgrade guide] for more info on Hotwire / Turbo integration.
         [changelog] https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
         [upgrade guide] https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-4.9.0-%5BHotwire-Turbo-integration%5D
         Post-install message from oauth2:
       You have installed oauth2 version 2.0.9, congratulations!      
       There are BREAKING changes if you are upgrading from < v2, but most will not encounter them, and updating your code should be easy!       
       We have made two other major migrations:
       1. master branch renamed to main
       2. Github has been replaced with Gitlab
       
       Please see:
       • https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2#what-is-new-for-v20
       • https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
       • https://groups.google.com/g/oauth-ruby/c/QA_dtrXWXaE
       
       Please report issues, and support the project! Thanks, |7eter l-|. l3oling
       
       Bundle completed (86.58s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v16.18.1-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.19
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
       
         config.omniauth :linkedin, Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:client_id], Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:client_secret]
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/config/initializers/devise.rb:14:in `block in <main>'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.9.2/lib/devise.rb:314:in `setup'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/config/initializers/devise.rb:11:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `load'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_22da9b42/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
```

I want to push my web app rails 7 in heroku..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would ensure that credentials have expected structure, if they do, did You set **RAILS_MASTER_KEY** environment variable on Your heroku app ?
All the details how to do it You can find on following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011825/3142249